# Passing Data in Dynamically generated links with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The Question:** Here is how I am passing data with js. Is this a good way to go about it or am I doing it wrong? It does work but it seems... suspicious, I suppose, to my relatively noob JS skills.

I have a custom grid plugin that generates a grid of data. Let's say it generates rows of user names with their id #, role, some dates, etc.

I want to be able click an "edit" link in each row that pops up a modal window to manage the data. Perhaps change a user's role.

The grid is generated by code wrapped in an anonymous function and the modal is generated by code wrapped in a different anonymous function. I need to populate the modal with the correct data for that particular clicked row.

What I have done is include the necessary data as custom attributes in the link that is clicked to manage that user's data. The generated link looks something like this:

`<a href="#" userrole="role1" userid="12345"> Manage </a>`

So clicking that link will launch the modal window and then I use some jquery to grab the attribute values and populate the modal. An example:

First, the code that handles the click (just assume that click handlers and other document.ready() stuff is assigned... I left that out for brevity but this is based on code that works correctly):

```
(function(){
    var EditUserClick = function(e) {
        userRole = $(this).attr('userrole'); //assign some values
        userId = $(this).attr('userid'); // assign some values

        OpenEditUserModal(userRole,userId); 
    }
});
```

Second, the code that handles the modal:

```
//Public stuff so it's accessible to the click.
var OpenEditUserModal;

(function(){
    OpenEditUserModal = function(userRole,userId){
        //code to handle the modal window opening can go here
        //populate the modal
        $('#userRole').text(userRole); // let's say this is a text field
        $('#userId').val(userId); //let's say this is a hidden form field
    }
});
```

So how about it? Is there a better way to get this data passed around than assigning it to made-up link attributes and passing it onclick to the next method? Any other advice is welcomed... always looking to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about your HTML documents passing the validation checks and the code works as it is - keep it that way.

As a less intrusive, more standards-compliant approach you could put all the stuff into the **href** attribute and simply parse the key-value pairs on click ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362683/what-javascript-library-should-i-use-for-parsing-url-parameters) for tips on how to do it).

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html?foo=bar&id=1">first</a>/li>
<li><a href="?foo=woo&id=2">second</a></li>
</ul>
```

Trivial JS for this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var querystring = $(this).attr('search');
    //console.log(querystring);

    // parse here and call OpenEditUserModal       
    return false;
});
```